# How to run a Makefile text into the script console in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-11.10, ubuntu-10.10

I want to install a driver which is a Makefile text and I don't know the way to run it in the console on Ubunto 12.10 (I'd really want to make myself clear Thank You)

Answer (score 0):

Use "make". Like this:
make; make install